# SilverStripe GridFieldExtension module GridFieldRequestHandler

Tags: silverstripe

The GridFieldExtension module comes with a `GridFieldRequestHandler` class which would enable extending the default GridField detail view (eg adding tabs or breadcrumbs). Unfortunately this feature is not included in the module's documentation.

Q: Can this class be used to add the following functionality to the GridField detail view?

- Back Button
- Save & Close
- Delete
- Userfriendly breadcrumbs

I'm familiar with the module BetterButtons that includes all these features, but it would be unnecessary to install yet another mod it if this mod already enables these features.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why not to install better buttons, it's a great module and with composer it is super easy to include...

Comment: It sure is a great mod. But as mentioned, I believe that the already-installed mod GridFieldExtension allows for this functionality and if thats the case I would be unnecessarily adding clutter to the installation by adding another mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would suggest using the [Better Buttons module](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons) instead of using `GridFieldRequestHandler`. The Better Buttons module is well maintained, full of features and works right out the box.

I don't believe it's worth writing all the code needed to use `GridFieldRequestHandler` to reproduce the Better Buttons functionality. I think Better Buttons is the right tool for this job and it warrants being installed even if we already have the `GridFieldExtension` module installed.

Comment: I took a look at the code required even for the simplest additions to gridfield and it appears its quite some work indeed. Installed BetterButtons..